# Android GCM Intent Service got stuck at Releasing Wakelock

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM for push notifications for my project, but I am stuck at releasing wakelock. I'm using the GCM code from android hive.

Below is my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.estorm.filingotp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<permission
    android:name="com.estorm.filingotp.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.estorm.filingotp.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<permission
    android:name="com.estorm.filingotp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.estorm.filingotp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/otp_appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

      <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.estorm.filingotp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

I Got the push well but the logcat gets stuck at Releasing Wavelock. And i am not using GCM at app launch. I am calling GCM in middle of the app. Both the class where i am calling GCM and GCM Intent Service are under same package name.
and my app has many packages just like Packagename.constants,Packagename.utils etc.

Please Help me. I got stuck on this for 2 days.

Here is My GCM Intent Service Code

```
    package com.estorm.filingotp;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.estorm.filingotp.constants.Globals;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "Test";
    public static final String SENDER_ID = "401189754081";
    public static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION = "com.estorm.filingotp.OTPLogon";
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    Context ctx;
    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, final String registrationId) {

        Log.v("", "Device registered: PUSHId = " + registrationId);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        // CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context,
        // getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        // if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
        // ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
        // } else {
        // Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
        // }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("", "Received message");
        Log.v("", "message is" + intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
        ctx = context;
        String other_key = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        Globals.IPtoken=other_key;
        generateNotification(context, other_key);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        // String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        // CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
        // generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        // CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error,
        // errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        // CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context,
        // getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.otp_appicon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, OTPLogon.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, message,
                message, intent);

        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
    }
```

And I used following code to call GCM in my Activity class

```
    private void gcm(final Context context) {
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            GCMIntentService.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    Globals.RegistrationId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
    Log.v("","reg uid is"+Globals.RegistrationId);

    if (Globals.RegistrationId.equals("")) {

        GCMRegistrar.register(context, GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);

    } else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            Log.v("", "GCM Display Message : "
                    + "Already registered");
        }
    }

}
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//      String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(
//              GCMIntentService.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        Log.v("", "broadcast done");
        new Apiconnector().execute();
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you post your code for handling incoming intent as well as the stack trace when LogCat catches your error?

Comment: Is your all GCM classes in main package??

Comment: Yes all are in main package @sur007

Comment: Can you post your GCM classes codes?

Comment: Please have a look at my code @sur007

Comment: You're using deprecated APIs (`GCMBaseIntentService`). Try to follow this tutorial instead and everything should work as you expect it https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: @Chowdary102 #kha is right you are using deprecated class. You should use IntentService

Comment: Also lookover this URL http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:
Extend GCMIntentService by Intent Service

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
Context context;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

     if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                sendNotification(msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
     GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

}
```

GCMBroadCastReceiver would look like

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


}

}
```

I looked over this [tutorial](http://techlovejump.in/2013/11/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/). Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **completeWakefulIntent(intent)** in order to release the wake lock. You have to pass the intent as the parameter which is the same intent that the WakefulBroadcastReceiver originally passed in.

Here is the sample code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;

public class SimpleWakefulService extends IntentService {
    public SimpleWakefulService() {
        super("SimpleWakefulService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // At this point SimpleWakefulReceiver is still holding a wake lock
        // for us.  We can do whatever we need to here and then tell it that
        // it can release the wakelock.  This sample just does some slow work,
        // but more complicated implementations could take their own wake
        // lock here before releasing the receiver's.
        //
        // Note that when using this approach you should be aware that if your
        // service gets killed and restarted while in the middle of such work
        // (so the Intent gets re-delivered to perform the work again), it will
        // at that point no longer be holding a wake lock since we are depending
        // on SimpleWakefulReceiver to that for us.  If this is a concern, you can
        // acquire a separate wake lock here.
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Running service " + (i+1)
                    + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        Log.i("SimpleWakefulReceiver", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        SimpleWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```